# How to forward test and plot?

Tags: matlab

Have received a lot of help. Will look for some more. Learning a lot by just going through the code.

I have thus far:

Loaded an xlsx file using xlsread function.

After this calculated the correlation coeff. Assigned it a variable(?).

Then used(Thanks @Robert P.):

```
BUYx = x(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))  
SELLy = y(find(APC < -2.9079,1,'first'))
BUYy = y(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
SELLx = x(find(APC > 0.44,1,'first'))
```

To get the first value meeting a particular condition.

Now I want to forward test from where the first value is received till another condition is met. At the same time I would like to make a plot the results.

I am just wondering where to start looking to code/try this.

Please point me in the direction of the functions required. I think it has to loop through all the elements after receiving entry. Not sure which is the right way to go about it.

Thanks

Context:

I am trying to test a StatsArbitrage strategy. I was using excel for the work but I can't seem to get the right functionality.

Basically, when we have an entry(any set of the BUY SELL) I want the system to automatically start calculating Profit/Loss from the next data point and give an output to a new variable. Then I would plot it. 
Then search for new entry and again start Profit/Loss calculation.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but `plot`can be used for plotting the results. A loop can be done using `for`loops. Or more elegant and faster using `arrayfun`

Comment: I agree, the question is hard to understand. @C.Colden: If it's faster is very dependent on the application. In newer versions of MATLAB loops are often faster than `arrayfun`.

Comment: Editing the question, it is a bit difficult to understand in current form.

Comment: I just went through the histc help/documentation. Doesn't seem like it would help. It will simply give me the values between a specified condition in a column. Still doesn't give me an idea of the Profit/Loss scenario from initiation of position to Close. Thanks @patrik